# Adicionar ponto a cada três números (milhar) em um tooltip do input range?

Tags: javascript, input, range

Como faço para adicionar "ponto de milhar" nos números, `R$1000` para `R$1.000` em um tooltip do input range:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```js
var mySlider = $("input#valores");

 $('#valores-credito, #valores-parcela').slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
   return 'R$ ' + value + '';
  }
 });

 var value = mySlider.slider('getValue');

   mySlider
     .slider('setValue', 0);
```

Comment: Já testaste usar o `.toLocaleString` como neste caso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147086/129 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brow, não sei se tem algo nativo que faça isso. Mas fiz essa função aí que resolve:

```
...
$('#valores-credito, #valores-parcela').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'R$ ' + milhar( value ) + '';
    }
});
...

function milhar(n){
    var n = ''+n, t = n.length -1, novo = '';

    for( var i = t, a = 1; i >=0; i--, a++ ){
        var ponto = a % 3 == 0 && i > 0 ? '.' : '';
        novo = ponto + n.charAt(i) + novo;
    }
    return novo;
}
```

Comment: Boa deu certo, obrigado.