# Incluir ponto e virgula a uma variável

Tags: javascript, number-format, replace

Olá, tenho um pequeno problema, tenho um número vindo de uma soma e eu necessito atribuir uma máscara para esse número. Fiz alguns testes até funcionou entretanto a máscara não ficou correta ao número.

```
var format = function (format, text) {  
    var array = text.split("");
    return format.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, function (index) {
        return array.splice(0, index.replace(/\D/g, "")).join("");
    });
};

var texto = format("{3}.{3}.{3}.{3},{2}", trasfN);

document.getElementById('calTotal').value = texto;
alert(texto);
```

Em um teste o numero está me retornando isso `162.312.0.` e o correto seria retornar `16.231,20*`

Comment: Não seria caso de usares o `toLocaleString` assim https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147086/129 ?

Comment: Tentei implementar, porém não funcionou vi outro exemplo usando o toLocaleString,   https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: var trasfN = parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2).toLocaleString('de-DE');

Comment: var trasfN = parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2).replace(".", "").toLocaleString('de-DE');

Comment: Tentei dessas duas formas, porém não houve diferença

Comment: O localeString é para numeros, não faças `toFixed`... Testa assim:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/2o6nb1hm/

Comment: Passei dessa forma: var trasfN = parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {maximumFractionDigits: 2});

Comment: Até funcionou, porém ele não retornou o 0 a direita, retornou dessa forma: 16.231,2

Comment: Ok, e fez o que querias? Se usas o `Math.round` nunca vais ter parte decimal.

Comment: estava usando o toFixed para retornar esse 0 e exibir o 1623120

Comment: Ok, usa `maximumFractionDigits` e `minimumFractionDigits`. Assim fixas o numero.

Comment: Testa assim `(1623120).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2
});` vai dar `1.623.120,00`

Comment: continua retornando somente uma casa após a virgula

Comment: var trasfN = parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {maximumFractionDigits: 3});

Comment: Viste o meu último comentário aqui? Testaste?

Comment: O numero completo que vem da soma seria esse: 16231.199999999999, ae eu trato com o parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100) para arredondar e o .toFixed(2) para so vim os 2 ultimos numeros após a virgula

Comment: Vi sim e o resultado foi o mesmo somente 1 numero após a virgula

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/2o6nb1hm/1/ é isso? E o que já tinha explicado nos comentários aqui. Tens de usar ambos o `minimumFractionDigits ` e o `maximumFractionDigits` para não ser nem mais nem menos que 2 casa decimais.

Comment: Isso mesmo muito obrigado!